# Building Nuxeo source code, dart issue

Tags: nuxeo

I am trying to build nuxeo source code & noticing below build issue. I noticed similar reported issue [here](https://jira.nuxeo.com/browse/NXDOC-1292). Has anyone faced similar issue?

Build error:
     [exec] Transform Dart2JS on nuxeo_api_playground|web/index.web_components.bootstrap.dart threw error: type 'PrefixElementX' is not a subtype of type 'MemberEntity' in type cast where

An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] /Users/kalava/Documents/Work/DAM/NuxeoOpenSource/nuxeo/addons/nuxeo-api-playground/src/main/dart/build.xml:9: exec returned: 65
[ERROR] around Ant part ...... @ 4:278 in /Users/kalava/Documents/Work/DAM/NuxeoOpenSource/nuxeo/addons/nuxeo-api-playground/target/antrun/build-main.xml

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the proper Dart version, as documented at https://doc.nuxeo.com/corg/installing-dart-and-related-tools/? Currently Nuxeo build requires Dart 1.23.x.

Comment: I have Dart 1.24.3 instead of 1.23.x, not able to get the formula for 1.23.x. Any suggestions?

Comment: Issue is resolved now, somehow when I run the mvn install it did not install dart. When in installed manually it took 1.24.0, I looked at Nuxeo checkin & found way to install 1.23.0. Issue is now resolved.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, please mark the question as resolved validating Florent's answer or posting the right solution if distinct.